# Formatting matrices to be read left to right

Tags: java, matrix, bluej

I need my matrices to look exactly like this.

```
 Here are the two matrices, and the result when added: 
    2   2   7   4        3   4   3   3        5   6  10   7
    4   4   8   8        6   8   5   5       10  12  13  13
    1   9   3   7        6   8   6   9        7  17   9  16
    2   3   2   9   +    4   4   7   1   =    6   7   9  10
    2   9   1   1        9   8   2   5       11  17   3   6
    6   1   8   4        4   8   2   2       10   9  10   6
```

Each number should use 4 positions in the output, and the + and = should be in the middle row, but I can not get the + and = signs to stay for smaller arrays. My problem may be with my if (i == 3 && j == 3) statements.
My code for this part is as follows.

```
   public static void printResult(int [][]array1, int [][]array2, int[][]sum, char arithmetic)
{
    // Declares 2-dimensional array the same size as one in parameters
    int [][]arraySum = new int [array1.length][array1[0].length];

    // Arithmetic characters to be printed when asked for
    String add = "+";
    String subtract = "-";
    String multiply = "*";
    String divide = "/";
    String remainder = "%";
    String equals = "=";

    // If arithmetic is addition to print matrices and add them to show result
    if (arithmetic == '+') {
        // Text for two matrices when added
        System.out.print("Here are the two matrices, and the result when added:\n");

        // For loop to print array1 + array2 = sum with format
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySum.length; i++) {
            // For loop to print out array 1 and add string
            for (int j = 0; j < arraySum[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%3s", array1[i][j] + " ");     
                if (i == 3 && j == 3) {
                    System.out.printf("%2s", add);
                }
            }
            System.out.print("\t");

            // For loop to print out array2 and equals string
            for (int k = 0; k < arraySum[i].length; k++) {
                System.out.printf("%3s", array2[i][k] + " ");
                if (i == 3 && k == 3) {
                    System.out.printf("%2s", equals);
                }
            }
            System.out.print("\t");

            // For loop to print out sum of array1 + array2
            for (int l = 0; l < arraySum[i].length; l++) {
                System.out.printf("%3s", sum[i][l] + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
    else if (arithmetic == '-') {
    }
    else if (arithmetic == '*') {
    }
    else if (arithmetic == '/') {
    }
    else if (arithmetic == '%') {
    }
}
```

Example of what I get for 3x3 arrays. (should still print + or =).

```
5  3  5      6  7  4    11 10  9
8  2  9      1  5  5     9  7 14
9  7  3      2  5  1    11 12  4
```

Comment: Hint: in a matrix of 3x3, `i` and `j` are going to run between `0` and `2`. Neither will ever be `3`. Also, `3` is not half of `3`. You should calculate the position of the operators based on the dimensions of the matrix, not a constant.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean. Your current problem is that the + and = symbols aren't being printed in the right place? Or they are not being printed at all? Also, why are you comparing if the variables (i,j,k) equal 3 to print, instead of the half of the matrices heigh?

Comment: Why do you add the print statement to the inner loop? If you need to print `+` or `=` you print it *after* the elements of the matrix. That means you should add that check/print statement *after* the inner loop (which also means you don't have to check the value of `j` or `k`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `if (i == arraySum.length/2 && j == arraySum[i].length-1)`.

Comment: I get the + and = in the right places now but would you happen to know why my formatting is still off, I am trying to get the numbers to line up with the wording.

Comment: Yes, probably it's because you need to put spaces in the other lines corresponding to the place the operator would be. Easiest way to fix would be `if (i == arraySum.length/2 && j == arraySum[i].length-1) print operator; if (i == arraySum.length/2 && j!=arraySum[i].length-1) print corresponding number of spaces;`. You can make that more elegant by using appropriate nested if / if / else statements.

Answer (score 1):

`i` and `j` are never 3 if your matrix is 3x3. If you want `+` and `=` in the middle then write something like this:

`if (i == arraySum.length / 2 && j == arraySum[i].length - 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Replace  `if (i == 3 && j == 3) {` with `if (i == (array1 / 2) && j == (array1 / 2)) {`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that in the for loop, you are adding the addition sign and the equals sign in the 4th row (0,1,2,3). When you only have three rows, it won't print. What you can do to make it in the middle is something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraySum.length; i++) {
    // For loop to print out array 1 and add string
    for (int j = 0; j < arraySum[i].length + 1; j++) {
        System.out.printf("%3s", array1[i][j] + " ");     
        if (i == Math.ceil(arraySum.length/2) && j == arraySum.length) {
            System.out.printf("%2s", add);
        }
    }
```

It will print the sign in the middle (height) and at the end (lengthwise) of the array. Just to be careful, it also uses the ceiling function to round up to the next integer.